# What functionality does 'convert case email to a contact' refer to on the EmailHeader documentation

Tags: case

Poking around the docs and found the following reference on the `EmailHeader` [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_header_emailheader.htm)

> The Salesforce user interface allows you to specify whether to send an
>   email when these events occur:
>
> - Create a Case
> - Create a CaseComment
> - **Convert Case email to a Contact**
> - Send a New User email notification
> - Make a resetPassword() call

I cant figure out what "Convert Case email to a Contact" is referring to.

Is there some automation around web-to-case or email to case that I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is not auto-creation of Contacts from the Case email. You need to build a trigger for that. I suggest you read this good article about this subject in which you will find a very good example on how to build such trigger. [Autocreating A Contact From Web To Case Or Email To Case](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=087300000006tuC)

I hope it helps. 
There is an app that does this but you will need to pay for it, [this one](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000001R5cyEAC)

Comment: Thanks Viasur that is my understanding as well.  Very curious what they could be referring to in the docs.